# How to centrally manage of files/directories in AWS just like Redhat Satellite?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, operating-system, cloud

I am running instances with RHEL6 & 7 distributions on AWS cloud. As a system administrator, I need a mechanism to centrally manage and synchronize the files on all instances. For eg: /etc/sudoers.d/ , /etc/sudoers, /etc/resolv.conf , /etc/nsswitch.conf, etc.. A central repository to manage these files and should push to the servers when they are not in sync or send an email if the file is not in sync on any instances. It should be similar to Redhat Satellite but I need to use AWS native services to attain this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ec2 systems manager.  https://aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/getting-started/

It's the closest thing I know to what you're describing.

Note that aws is distro agnostic, and can't marshal files into the virtual machines ( after all, be they're virtual machines in a very real sense, and their file systems are not really accessible to the hypervisor).

But what you can do is he an agent running which can grab the files, which is surely how satellite works too.

If you want to be cloud native, you might also want to use an auto sanding group with a cfn -hup script running in the instances.  It can detect configuration changes and run the supplied automation.  But I'm guessing you're going for long lived instances, not cloud elasticity?

Comment: yes these are long lived ec2 instances. I checked the systems manager functionality. But to automate between the staging of files (may be using S3) and ensuring they are in sync with the files in the ec2 instances (say files like /etc/sudoers) that dynamically gets added while users spun up the instance is a complex task.

Comment: Indeed it is.  Have you received about using chef, salt, ansible, or puppet (or similar configuration management tool) to handle this?